# Oracle delete and update billions of duplicate records from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Versioned Table has duplicate address records and needs to be deleted as below
1: Find duplicate records from a table as below
Address

```
adr_id | ver_id  | address
1       1      newYork
1       2      newYork
1       3      newYork
4       1      Washington
4       2      Washington
```

2: Insert new records as below

```
adr_id | ver_id  | address
11    0    newYork
12    0    Washington
```

3: Delete existing duplicate records so final table would look like #2.

Note: Table has billions of records and required to be done in minimum time with best database technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement correlated on the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY adr_id) AS cnt,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY adr_id ORDER BY ver_id) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (src.cnt > 1 AND dst.ROWID = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET   adr_id = YOUR_ADR_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,
        ver_id = 0
  DELETE WHERE rn > 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE your_adr_id_sequence START WITH 11;

CREATE TABLE table_name (adr_id, ver_id, address) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 'Washington' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'Washington' FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| ADR_ID | VER_ID | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 0 | newYork |
| 14 | 0 | Washington |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/en6inE9j)

Comment: This looks working but how about updating parent table for newly normalized record ids as asked here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74315449/process-and-update-billions-of-records-from-oracle-table-in-minimum-time) Also will it work for 2 billion of records in a given table any pointer here

Comment: @umang [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (with a [MRE]) for that as updating two tables with the same changes is a very different problem to updating a single table and solutions that work for this question are not going to work when you have referential constraints involved.

Comment: It will work for 2 billion rows (although it really depends how you quantify the term "work" as it may take some time).

Comment: Rephrased here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348558/remove-duplicate-records-from-child-table-and-update-parent-with-newly-inserted)