# Remove duplicate records from child table and update parent with newly inserted child records reference id for billions of records

Tags: java, oracle

Employee has multiple versions of addresses and given addresses are being duplicate needs to be removed and replaced with single unique address row and update parent table with newly inserted address id reference in optimal way .

```
CREATE TABLE address (adr_id, ver_id, address) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 'Washington' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'Washington' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE employee (emp_id,adr_id,ver_id,) AS
SELECT 100,1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200,1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300,1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 400,4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 500,4, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Before**

```
employee
id | adr_id | ver_id
100     1       1           
200     1       2
300     1       3
400     4       1   
500     4       2 

Address 
adr_id | ver_id  | address
1       1      newYork
1       2      newYork
1       3      newYork
4       1      Washington
4       2      Washington
```

**Expected After**

```
Address
adr_id | ver_id  | address
11    0    newYork
12    0    Washington

employee
id | adr_id | ver_id
100     11      1           
200     11      2
300     11      3
400     12      1   
500     12      2
```

Note: There is foreign key constraint between Employee and Address table with composite key comprising of adr_id & ver_id
This is being done using stored procedure but its too slow is there any parallel processing can be done here by some way?

Comment: How are you retaining the FK if the address table now has a (dummy?) `ver_id` of zero? Do you even still need that column in that table?

Comment: written stored procedure which will insert new address with new addr_id and ver_id=0 (here 0 indicates address is normalized) and update parent table where  duplicate addr_id  &ver_id are being used with new addr_id and then delete duplicate records in conclusion insert new address in child table and then make it refer in parent table so eventually all duplicate records become orphan and eligible to delete

Comment: If you're only updating the employee table with the new `addr_id` (e.g. 11) but leaving the `ver_id` alone (e.g. 1/2/3), as your comment says and you've shown in your 'expected after' data then the PK/FK doesn't work - you'd either need to keep the old address rows with those `ver_id` values, or update all the employee `ver_id` values to zero, or change the PK/FK to only cover the `addr_id` column (and maybe drop `ver_id` from the address table if it isn't used any more).

Comment: This is framework requirement and this is workaround but I want Address record to be referred by adr_id (PK ) only in future (Will skip ver_id in future queries ) while referring address record as adr_id is going to be unique per row. My only concern is how can I do these steps in minimum time . I have written stored procedure it just works but slow.